# Convert multi PDF document to several Image files

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick-convert

How can I convert a multi-page-PDF into several JPG or TIFF?

When I use

```
 convert "abc.PDF" "abc.JPG"
```

then just the first page of the PDF is being converted. Is it possible to convert every page of "abc.PDF" to several JPG-files?

Comment: actually the way you use `convert` should create a jpg of each pdf page, see e.g. [here](http://superuser.com/q/633698). So something is strange here.

Comment: You command should work as it is. The only reasons which come up in my mind when speculating about why you get the first page only:  ***(1)*** Processing stops on 2nd page because of some bug in the PDF, in Ghostscript or in ImageMagick.  -- ***(2)*** Your ImageMagick version is too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert multipage PDF files into multiple JPEGs (one file per page) easily when using `convert`.

Here is a command to process just pages 1--5:

```
convert PDF32000_2008.pdf[0-4] page-%d.jpg
```

(**`[0-4]`** means pages 1--5. The page indexing is 0-based!)

However, this does not give you much control about the resulting quality. The only thing you can add is `-density 150` or `-density 300` to increase the resolution of your images. (`convert` by default uses `-density 72` which is 72 PPI.)

Also, be aware that ImageMagick is not able to process PDFs all by itself. It employs *Ghostscript* as its 'delegate' to handle PDF files. You can see this if you add `-verbose` to your command line:

```
convert -verbose -density 200 ~/Downloads/PDF32000_2008.pdf[0-4] page-%d.jpg
  [....]
  [ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT      \
                  -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2      \
                 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
                 "-r200x200" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=5                      \
                 "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-63898lc1DhZVuD6lu%d"          \
                 "-f/var/tmp/magick-63898h8-BZJ59LyhQ"                       \
                 "-f/var/tmp/magick-638989MxSe0EALH5F"
```

So in many cases where you want to convert PDF pages to images it has advantages to run Ghostscript directly...